# How to create a slave of large mongodb databases

Tags: mongodb

As we know, mongodb has limited oplog.

If I just create a new slave, everything in the database is not sync yet. Everything in the database is bigger than any oplog.

So how do I get around this? Does that mean we cannot create a new slave that's bigger than the oplog? Does mongodb has other mechanism for synching database besides that oplog?

How exactly it's done then if true?

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database is of reasonable size, and you have a snapshot, you can copy over the files (specified by the --dbpath flag on startup or in the config file) to allow the new replica set member to come online quicker. However, an initial sync may still happen.

Conceptually, the following things happen

1. Start up the new member as part of the replica set
2. Add it to the rs.conf()
3. The new replicaset is synced off the closest (could be a primary or a secondary) and will begin pulling data from it (initial sync) and mark a point in the oplog for it's own reference.
4. The new secondary will then apply the oplog from it's own timestamp that it has copied from the other replica set member.

If the sync fails, another initial sync (from the very start) will happen. For really large datasets, the sync can take some time.

In reply to your questions

***Does that mean we cannot create a new slave that's bigger than the oplog?***

You can create and add a new member that is bigger than the oplog

***Does mongodb has other mechanism for synching database besides that oplog?***
Yes, the initial sync and the file copy mentioned above.

Comment: I see. So there is this initial sync. But during the initial sync the master changes all the time. How does the new database grab the snapshot of the master for the initial sync?

Comment: I'm not fully following your question.

If the node you're replicating **from** has a hiccup (looses network, node reboots, etc) then the sync will have to start again from a new node. This gives us eventual consistency between all nodes in the replica set.

Comment: Rescync can't be done by simple copying right because when the copying is in process the main database change. So how do they resync? This is already beyond the question. Should I create another question? Do they lock files and create copy and then resync, then follow the oplog?

Comment: No, this question is fine - I just didn't go into large detail about the oplog. When a sync starts, the node you're syncing **from** makes a note in it's oplog of when the sync started. The new node then uses this note in the oplog to gain consistency with the rest of the replica set members.

Since oplogs are capped collections, there _is_ the possibility of the new node never being able to catch up as the timestamp in the oplog is overwritten by newer operations. Increasing the oplog size is the recommended way to counteract this if the sync fails a few times.